# Classes of metric spaces with additional structure

Tags: metric-spaces

As is often the case in mathematics there is an option of studying a more general topic but this comes with a price of losing some interesting properties which are only present in the more specialized area.

In this case, I am interested in learning about relative usefulness of a metric space carrying some additional structure. To give some obvious examples:

- **Polish space** (a separable and completely metrizable space) is very useful in measure and probability theory
- **Banach space** (a complete normed vector space) is a cornerstone of a functional analysis

I want to learn about more examples of this kind (not necessarily as important though) to get a better idea about how different kinds of metric spaces look like and also about the fields that are based on them.

> 1.  What are some other structures one might impose on a metric space to obtain interesting classes of spaces?

In a related spirit

> 2.  Are there properties (e.g. completeness, separability) that are so important that they are almost always required in some application (or even some field)? If so, what is that application, what are those properties and why are they important (or equivalently, what fails when they are not present)?

*Note:* sorry, if this is too vague or too basic. But I don't have a solid mathematical background, so it's hard to know where to look for answers to these questions. I am just trying to learn about topology in general and about metric spaces in particular (mainly because of their applications in probability theory) and I will definitely accept as an answer a reference to a standard literature.

Comment: Honestly, have you read the wikipedia page on metric spaces before posting? It seems to me that more or less any reasonable property can be found there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space and then by browsing through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Metric_geometry

Comment: @Theo: I have read the entry on metric spaces and while it contains useful information I believe it doesn't really answer my question (e.g. there's no mention of the Polish space at all). As for the category page, I haven't seen that but it also doesn't seem to answer my question (again no mention of Polish spaces). Just throwing a glossary of some random terms that are somehow connected with metric spaces, you're not really helping, sorry.

Comment: I think your 1st question is too vague. One can always think up extra "bells and whistles" to add a given definition/concept; but that's not really how one should do mathematics, IMHO. If you want to learn about topological and metric spaces then a good introductory textbook (Sutherland's "Introduction to metric and topological spaces" is a bit basic, but might do) is worth far more than a list of cool-sounding things

Comment: Metric spaces are an extremely useful abstraction of structure found in many interesting examples. It is better to learn about these examples rather than ask "what can we add to the definition of a metric space to obtain interesting things"?

Comment: On looking at that wikipedia entry, I think that the examples given there are worth looking at. Probably the reason why you don't see a mention of Polish spaces is that they are topological spaces that happen to be separable and metrizable; they are not metric spaces per se, because different metrics can give the same topology. Unusurprisingly, Wikipedia's entry on Polish spaces http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space is a better place to look for those examples.

Comment: @Yemon: sorry, if I didn't make myself clear but what I am really after is some classification of metric space, so I can make some sense of them. Classification seems to me a basic way to learn about some topic. What I am asking about is essentially those types and why are they useful. As for the Polish space... every complete separable metric space is Polish, and so is an important example of a metric space. The fact that such a basic example is missing suggests that other similarly basic examples are missing too and so the entry isn't terribly useful for my purposes.

Comment: @Yemon: still, thanks for the effort. I'll try to look at the book you suggested. As I said, it is quite probably that my question doesn't need more than going through basic results. The hard part is figuring out where to find those :)

Comment: A POLISH SPACE IS NOT A METRIC SPACE. It is a separable topological space which can be equipped with a complete metric. There are many different metric spaces on $R^2$ which yield the same (usual) topology, and making a list of all of them will tell you very little of worth about the Polish space $R^2$ that is not already obvious from using the "usual" metric

Comment: @Marek: Your comment "every complete separable metric space is Polish" suggests (to me) that you missed the point of Yemon's pervious comment.  Although what you wrote is true, it's also true that some *incomplete* separable metric spaces are Polish (because the same topology can be induced by a different, complete metric).  The property of being Polish is a matter of topology; even if you're given a topology as induced by a metric, you may need to change the metric (but not the topology) to see that your space is Polish.

Comment: @Andreas: I didn't miss this point at all and am not sure why you would say so. In any case, I think I have by now stated quite clearly what I am after and if no one intends to point me into right direction but instead only dwell on how I misunderstood this and forget to read that (which I didn't, in both cases), I might as well delete this question... Sorry for taking your time, I didn't realize the question would be so badly received.

Comment: Marek: I guess one thing which confuses me is that what you say in the comments is not quite what you say in the body of the main question. Your main question seems to suggest you want to learn about Polish spaces, in which case the comments of Andreas and myself apply; but your comments seem to want a classification of metric spaces in the belief that such a thing will be useful to you. I am not aware of any such classification, and am not convinced it would be useful to you. Not everything in mathematics is easily classified, and this is why one has a general framework to unify examples

Comment: Also, in response to your comment: we are trying to point you in the right direction, but you keep saying this is not what you are after...

Comment: @Yemon: no, I don't want to learn only about Polish spaces (or rather Polish metric spaces), that was just one particular example that illustrates that certain topological property is required in some area. I wanted to get a list of similar examples to better understand which properties (or additional structures) are important and why, thereby better understanding classes of metric spaces. If such a list/classification doesn't exist (which might very well be possible) then that's just fine as an answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: As an additional property, what about compatible group or vector space structures. For instance, a real topological vector space is metrizable if and only if it has a countable basis of nbd's of the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Another class of metric spaces that are of interest are length spaces. Roughly speaking, these are spaces in which you can measure the length of paths. The distance is then the inf of all lengths paths pinned at the two points. Gromov talks about these as does a book by Borago and Borago (the exact citations elude me).